# How do I add ASP.NET MVC 3 Web Application in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3

I have VS 2010 as follow:

> Microsoft Visual Studio 2010
>
> Version 10.0.30319.1 RTMRel
>
> Microsoft .NET Framework Version 4.0.30319 RTMRel
>
> Installed Version: Ultimate

ASP.NET MVC 3 Web Application project template is not available.
I just see ASP.NET MVC 2 Web Application project template. How do I add MVC 3?

Just trying to follow the right path before I screw up my current installation.

Thanks

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You need to go to http://www.asp.net/mvc/mvc3 and download the MVC3 installer. Then you will be good to go.

Comment: I saw some people had issues with that stuff. Look here http://haacked.com/archive/2011/04/12/introducing-asp-net-mvc-3-tools-update.aspx

Comment: All I can say is that I've installed it with the downloaded installer and it works perfectly.

Comment: Seriously, how can this installer take this long? I'm at 30 min and it's still going...

Answer (score 8):

Download and install MVC 3 via **web platform installer** http://www.microsoft.com/web/gallery/install.aspx?appid=MVC3

When you create a new project, make sure you have selected **.NET Framework 4** in the drop down.  You should be able to see both ASP.NET MVC 2 Web Application and **ASP.NET MVC 3 Web Application**

Answer (score 1):

If you have the **Web Platform Installer**, you can get it that way, and it's probably the easiest way.  If you don't have the Web Platform Installer, get it here:

[Web Platform Installer](http://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

None of these worked for me. If you're using `VS2010 SP1` then take a look at this article.

It worked.

Extract the exe with Winrar or similar and run the MSI files manually.

Apparently the exe fails due to the newer version of NuGet.

> http://tedgustaf.com/en/blog/2011/4/installing-asp-net-mvc3-on-visual-studio-2010-sp1/

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to download and install it from the official Microsoft ASP.NET MVC site

[ASP.NET MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc)

Answer (score 0):

As Troyka suggested you need *"ASP.NET MVC 3 Tools for Visual Studio"* but in my case installation failed and logs said I had a later version of MVC 3 installed.

So I had to

1. Uninstall MVC3 from *Control Panel\Programs\Programs and Features*
2. Install *"ASP.NET MVC 3 Tools for Visual Studio 2010"*