# Is there a way to prevent the output of a new line character after an asp tag?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I'm working on a web application written in ASP.NET MVC 2. I'm creating templates for my views, and I'm using the `asp:ContentPlaceHolder` so that I can paste in the content into the template.

Here is an example of a master template:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewMasterPage" %><!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge, chrome=1">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title><asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="TitleContent" runat="server" /></title>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MetaContent" runat="server" />
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="StyleContent" runat="server" />
</head>

<body>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server" />
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ScriptContent" runat="server" />
</body>

</html>
```

Now, if only `MainContent` is replace with `<h1>Hello World</h1>` and all the other place holders are left blank, then the html output looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge, chrome=1">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Home</title>


</head>

<body>

    <h1>Hello World</h1>


</body>

</html>
```

The browser doesn't seem to mind, but I do. I would like my output to look like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge, chrome=1">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Home</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Hello World</h1>
</body>

</html>
```

Is there a way to prevent the output of new line if the content of the place holder is left blank?

Comment: @abatishchev Yes sir.

Comment: It's pretty old version of the MVC framework. So just to make sure.

Comment: I'm still using Visual Studio 2010. Can't afford to upgrade right now.

Comment: You can't install and use basically any version of MVC despite the version of VS. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5812102/how-do-i-add-asp-net-mvc-3-web-application-in-visual-studio-2010

Comment: @Marcos Visual Studio Express is free, though if that version won't work for you 2010 can use newer versions of MVC.

Comment: Modify master template to remove newlines between placeholders and add an extra newline in each item template? I can't check, i don't have such version of MVC

Comment: @KirillSlatin That is actually what I've been doing for some templates (In fact, look at the doctype in the example I posted, it's doing exactly that), but it makes the code hard to maintain. However, I'm looking for a more elegant solution.